# R Fastest way to execute a loop when it's condition changes inside

Tags: r, data.table

In my code I have a function that executes a while loop like this:

```
     DT <- data.table(id = 1, id_node = 2, checked = 'F');

     while (nrow(DT[checked == 'F']) > 0) {
        ... code doing things ...
        ....
        ifelse((condition),
            DT <- rbindlist(list(DT,data.table(id=2,id_node=3,checked='F')),
            DT[id %in% otherDT$id, checked := 'T']);
     }
```

The condition `DT[checked == 'F']`, it is not static, 
since it changes within the loop, adding new elements with `checked = 'F'`, or modifying the ones it already has with `checked = 'T'`, depending on a series of conditions.

I am looking for the fastest way to perform this type of loops in which the conditioner changes within the loop.

This problem comes from the fact that I have to go through a tree, which can grow as I go through it (new branches), and I need to mark as checked those branches that I have already gone through, until they are all marked with `checked = 'T'`.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your data, the `checked` column seems to be character. I suggest you convert it to logical. `DT[!checked]` when `checked` is logical should be a lot faster than `DT[checked == 'F']` when checked is a character. Especially if you're checking conditions multiple times. Logical columns would also take up less memory than character columns

Comment: I am sure that your suggestion is an improvement, even soo I have not seen changes in the execution time. There is some other approach to my while problem?

Comment: The ```code doing things``` is probably where you should focus on. However, if you know the exact row number - which you likely don't - you could always look at the ```set()``` function which updates the data.table by reference without accessing everything.

Comment: The `set()` function is equal in performance to 'data.table[condition, column := value]'?

Comment: I modified the `code doing things` changing the use of `nrow(DT[checked == 'F']` and its assignment by reference, `DT[id %in% otherDT$id, checked := 'T'])` by the use of vector variables created at the beginning with a fixed dimension. `variable << - rep (NA, 200);` and then accessing it through its index. In this way I have improved the performance by 30-40% approximately. In summary, change a growing data.table for static vector. But if I can improve the performance, I'm open to other suggestions.